# problem getting num_rows with PDO class in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, oop, pdo

I have just changed my database connection. I am not used to the PDO class or OOP yet. Anyway, I connect to the db like this:

```
        $dsn = "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME;
        try
        {
            $this->db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        }
        catch ( Exception $e )
        {
            die ( $e->getMessage() );
        }
```

I am trying to get number of rows from this query:

```
    $ip = $this->ip(); 
    $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `login_failed`
            WHERE `ip` = :ip AND `time` BETWEEN NOW( ) - INTERVAL 120 MINUTE AND NOW( )
            LIMIT 3";
    try 
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result = $stmt->execute(); // $result = true
        $n = $stmt->num_rows ; // n = NULL?
        $stmt->closeCursor(); 
    }       
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        die ($e->getMessage() ); 
    }
```

In `phpmyadmin` I get a result so my query is correct, but `$n` is `NULL` for some reason.. How do I get number of rows with `PDO`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$stmt` is of type [`PDOStatement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php). That class has no `num_rows` property.

You might be looking for [`rowCount`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) instead, but the documentation for that states:

> If the last SQL statement executed by
>   the associated PDOStatement was a
>   SELECT statement, some databases may
>   return the number of rows returned by
>   that statement. However, this
>   behaviour is not guaranteed for all
>   databases and should not be relied on
>   for portable applications.

The long and the short if it is that, if you want to actually `SELECT` all that data, you can reliably determine how many rows were returned by iterating over the result set (or just call [`fetchAll`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and count the items in the array). If you don't need the data but just a number, use `SELECT COUNT` instead.

So, to count the rows without changing the query:

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); // assuming $result == true
$n = count($rows);
```

Comment: +1 for being faster than me while still also managing to include the rowCount disclaimer.

Comment: @Charles: There are only so many ways to skin a cat... *very* similar responses. I 'll upvote you any chance I get if only for being so disciplined :)