# getting undesired result by prepare statement mysqli php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi, I am new to PHP and I am trying to write prepare statement for login but as given below code my query is not getting any row but getting `field_count`.

And if I put that

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName = 'DemoUser'
```

in direct database I am getting one row but here `$stmt->num_rows` is zero. What am I missing.

```
// in connections.php
$dbh = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

include('connections.php');
include('config.php');
include('comman_functions.php');

if(isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password']!=''
    && isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username']!=''
    && isset($_POST['location']) && $_POST['location']!='') {

    $username = "DemoUser";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName =? ");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();  
    error_log($stmt->num_rows); 
    if($stmt->num_rows>0){
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    error_log("logged in!!!");

    $stmt->close();

    } else {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Invalid Username or Password';
        header('Location:index.php');
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Please provide Username and Password';
    header('Location:index.php');
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably with $stmt->num_rows.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556540/problem-getting-num-rows-with-pdo-class-in-php

Comment: i am using mysqli $dbh = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

Answer (score 0):

Try THis!

U need to add `$stmt->bind_result();` after `$stmt->execute();`

```
$dbh = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);// in connections.php



<?php
  include('connections.php');
  include('config.php');
  include('comman_functions.php');

  if(isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password']!='' && isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username']!='' && isset($_POST['location']) && $_POST['location']!=''){

    $username = "DemoUser";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName =? ");
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
      $stmt->execute();  
      $stmt->bind_result();
      error_log($stmt->num_rows); 
    if($stmt->num_rows>0){
      $row = $stmt->fetch();
        error_log("logged in!!!");

      $stmt->close();

    }else{
      $_SESSION['error'] = 'Invalid Username or Password';
      header('Location:index.php');
    }
  }else{
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Please provide Username and Password';
    header('Location:index.php');
  }

?>
```

Comment: thanks for ans sir ,but i am using $dbh = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database); row count is PDO function

Comment: hey i just tried what you said ..but still same not getting data from data base but able to find count of column number from $stmt->field_count

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems making work this num_rows, you have to declare `->store_result()` first.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root", "", "tables");

$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1");
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();

$rows = $query->num_rows;

echo $rows;
```

Comment: hey i am getting row count but not able to fetch() data from that object :(